# JavaScript Regex not after a specified character

Tags: javascript, regex

How to match a pattern that is not after a specified character?

Let's say the specified character is a space and we want to match @match

Eg: @match - finds "@match", because no space before it

@match and @match - finds the first @match but not the second one because there is a space before it.

ANTHING@match - should also find "@match", because no space before it.

Comment: Can you post an example showing what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this?

```
/[^ ](pattern)/
```

But that won't match patterns at the beginning of the string, so you could use that in combination with:

```
/^pattern/
```

Comment: `/([^ ]|^)pattern/g` goes close, though I'm not exactly sure what the OP is after.

Comment: Wow, can you really use `^` as a character like that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure... but for all trying to answer this question, here's a jsfiddle where you can just enter your REGEX where it says INSERT_REGEX_HERE and see if it works. Enjoy!

```
<div ng-app>
<form novalidate name="myForm">
<input name="input1" type="text" ng-model="input1" ng-pattern="/INSERT_REGEX_HERE/" />
<div ng-show="myForm.input1.$dirty && myForm.input1.$error.pattern">DOES NOT MATCH     REGEX</div>
</form> 
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MLhqT/2/

Comment: LOL, What kind of answer begins with 'I'm not sure'? Also where's the link?